# Why does arr[i++] vs arr[i]++ do?

Tags: c++

Why does the first code below print out 15, not 20?

```
     #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
     int main(){
     int arr[] = {10,15,20,15,30};
     for(int i =1; i<3;i++){
     cout<<arr[i++];
      }
   }
```

and why does this code print out 15 20.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
      int arr[] = {10,15,20,15,30};
      for(int i =1; i<3;i++){
      cout<<arr[i]++;
      }
     }
```

Comment: the first one you can reference : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec `int i = 0; int a = i++;  // a = 0; i = 1;` . I'm not sure you got the second '++' on the right spot for the expected result.

Comment: Move back a notch and make sure you understand what `x++` does. Write a little program like `int x = 10; cout << x<< endl; cout << x++ << endl; cout << x<< endl;` and watch what happens. Then do it again with `++x` so that you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for(int i =1; i<3;i++){
     cout<<arr[i++];
 }
```

after every iteration, i++ will increment the value of i. but as you've incremented it inside the loop also, first time, i will be initialized with 1, then inside the loop, it will print the value of a[i] and increment the value of i, which now will be 2, the loop iteration is over, that means the i++ you used as third parameter in the loop will increment the value of i again. now it becomes 3, and 3 is not less than 3, condition becomes false, it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, loop is starting from 1. It is pointing to element 15(as array index starts from 0).

In the print statement, the value i is getting incremented so now i is at index 2(value 20). Now the control reaches the "increment section" of the for loop. The value of i is now incremented to 3.

Now control checks with the condition of the loop and loop terminates.

In second code, you are simply incrementing the value inside the array index(index is not getting incremented). Try adding another print statement after that. You will get 1621